# Opencart 3 theme development

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Could someone explain how to start and enable custom Opencart 3 theme? There are plenty of tutorials for Opencart 2 and just a bit of unclear posts at forums for Opencart 3, but after trying for few times all I get are "Theme not set up for this store" error and "Disabled" status next to my custom theme in settings, even tho in edit screen the selected option is Enabled. Thanks.

**EDITED**: The answer is [this topic](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=187122), it worked after replacing "theme_default" to "theme_YOURTHEMENAME" in all 3 files...

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it too if you found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**: The answer is [this topic](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=187122), it worked after replacing "theme_default" to "theme_YOURTHEMENAME" in all 3 files...

Answer (score 1):

Creating a theme in OpenCart 3 is a bit more complicated than in 1.5 where all you had to do was make a folder in the theme directory and copy only the files from the default theme that you wanted to change.

In a nutshell there are 3 files a theme needs in the admin which can be copied and renamed from default but you must change lots of references to the default theme inside them (which isn't exactly all instances of the word "default"):

```
/admin/controller/extension/theme/default.php
/admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/default.php
/admin/view/template/extension/theme/default.twig
```

I've made a free downloadable template copy of the default OpenCart 3 themes with really clear instructions on how to rename it and install it here:
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-an-opencart-3-theme/

(It is based on the forum post from other answers here https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=187122 but hopefully is clearer, easier and simpler to follow.)